# fluentd tag rewrite on kubernetes logs only works when appending original tag

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

This is in relation to [fluentd create tag based on key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806299/fluentd-create-tag-based-on-key-value)
.

The only way it seems to work is to append the original tag to the end of the new tag like so:

```
<match kubernetes.**>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key $['kubernetes']['namespace_name']
    pattern ^(.+)$
    tag $1.${tag}
  </rule>
</match>
```

What I'd like to do is not append the original tag to the end:

```
<match kubernetes.**>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key $['kubernetes']['namespace_name']
    pattern ^(.+)$
    tag $1
  </rule>
</match>
```

When configured in this way nothing is logged into Elastic.

Reading the docs for [fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter) the Kubernetes example only shows appending original tag to end of new tag.

I've tested this on non Kubernetes nginx logs and it does work using only the `tag $1` to rewrite the tag.

How do I achieve this on Kubernetes example above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running the above test with quite a bit of additional fluentd config including a number of filters.

I took it right back to the beginning and created a very basic fluend configuration and the above now works as expected.  I just need to understand what it is about the full fluentd configuration with the additional filters that is breaking it.

Comment: Did you find the issue?